# ng-file-upload to S3 returnin 403 with CORS and Angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ng-file-upload

i'm trying to do a simple web page where the user can upload an image, crop it and then submit, so the cropped image goes to a s3 bucket. I got the cropping part going, but the uploading is returning a 403:

```js
var app = angular.module('fileUpload', ['ngFileUpload', 'ngImgCrop']);
var file = "test image"

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout', function ($scope, Upload, $timeout) {
    $scope.upload = function (dataUrl) {
        Upload.upload({
            url: 'https://MY-BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/', //S3 upload url including bucket name,
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                file: file,
                key: "test-image", // the key to store the file on S3, could be file name or customized
                AWSAccessKeyId: "MY-AWS-KEY",
                acl: 'private', // sets the access to the uploaded file in the bucket: private, public-read, ...
                policy: "./policy.json", // base64-encoded json policy (see article below)
                signature: "MY-SIGNATURE", // base64-encoded signature based on policy string (see article below)
                "Content-Type": "image/jpeg" != '' ? file.type : 'application/octet-stream', // content type of the file (NotEmpty)
                // filename: "test image", // this is needed for Flash polyfill IE8-9
            },
        }).then(function (response) {
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.result = response.data;
            });
        }, function (response) {
            if (response.status > 0) $scope.errorMsg = response.status 
                + ': ' + response.data;
        }, function (evt) {
            $scope.progress = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        });
    }
}]);
```

```css
<style>
    .cropArea {
    background: #E4E4E4;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:500px;
    height:350px;
}
form .progress {
    line-height: 15px;
}
.progress {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    border: 3px groove #CCC;
}
.progress div {
    font-size: smaller;
    background: orange;
    width: 0;
}
  </style>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="angular.js"></script>
  <script src="ng-img-crop.js"></script>
  <script src="./bower_components/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload.js"></script>
  <script src="./bower_components/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload-shim.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ng-img-crop.css">
  <script src="uploader.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body ng-app="fileUpload" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <form name="myForm">
        <div>Crop Image and Upload</div>
        <button ngf-select ng-model="picFile" accept="image/*">Select Picture</button>
        <div ngf-drop ng-model="picFile" ngf-pattern="image/*" class="cropArea">
            <img-crop image="picFile  | ngfDataUrl" result-image="croppedDataUrl" ng-init="croppedDataUrl=''" change-on-fly="1" area-type="square" result-image-size="250">
            </img-crop>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img ng-src="{{croppedDataUrl}}" />
        </div>
        <button ng-click="upload(croppedDataUrl)">Submit</button> 
            
        <span class="progress" ng-show="progress >= 0">
          <div style="width:{{progress}}%" ng-bind="progress + '%'"></div>
        </span>
        <span ng-show="result">Upload Successful</span>
        <span class="err" ng-show="errorMsg">{{errorMsg}}</span>
    </form>
</body>







<!-- 


<img-crop image="myImage" result-image="myCroppedImage" change-on-fly="1" area-type="square" result-image-size="250"></img-crop>
 -->
```

I crop the image and hit the Submit button, then receive the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://MY-BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

I have CORS enabled on the bucket to PUT, POST and GET, what can I do?

Comment: Your CORS settings are probably wrong. See if you can make a cURL request to it.

Comment: I was able to do a cURL request, the bucket returned to the terminal (GET). This is my CORS configuration: 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
`

Comment: by doing <AllowedMethod>OPTIONS</AllowedMethod> ?

Comment: EDIT: i added `<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>` on the cors configuration, and everything seemed to work fine, and a file is sent to the bucket, but its not an image, its a 10 byte file that give me "access denied" when i try to open it

Comment: Where the file in ` file: file,` come from? Maybe it is not a real File object.

Comment: I'll check on that. It should actually be the cropped image, which is not saved on any local file i believe, it generates a code for the image. I got this code from the following example, and (tried to) adapt it to upload to s3: http://jsfiddle.net/xxo3sk41/1/